# How to display the IP address of the sender when rsyslog rejects a UDP message?

Tags: rsyslog

Environment is Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with rsyslog 5.8.6.

I've got rsyslog configured to receive messages via UDP over the standard port 514.  It allows one specific host to send messages to it:

```
$AllowedSender UDP, 192.168.4.1
```

When I send a message from a different server, it rejects the message and logs:

```
rsyslogd: UDP message from disallowed sender discarded
```

Is it possible to configure rsyslog to include the IP address of the rejected sender?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the version 5 source (https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/archive/v5-stable.zip) and looked at *plugins/imudp/imudp.c*.  In this file, it's a hardcoded message with no option for displaying the sender's *frominet* IP address:

```
if(glbl.GetOption_DisallowWarning) {
    time_t tt;
    datetime.GetTime(&tt);
    if(tt > ttLastDiscard + 60) {
        ttLastDiscard = tt;
        errmsg.LogError(0, NO_ERRCODE,
        "UDP message from disallowed sender discarded");
    }
}
```

I also found that *tools/syslogd.c* contains a now-unused remnant *chkMsgAgainstACL()* that did display the *fromHost* value.

```
errmsg.LogError(0, NO_ERRCODE,
    "UDP message from disallowed sender %s discarded",
    (char*)fromHost);
```

I'm not sure why Rainer decided not to keep that feature.  He does discuss some performance issues around this section of the code here: http://blog.gerhards.net/2009/11/acls-imudp-and-accepting-messages.html

In any case, it looks like I'd have to compile my own version of rsyslogd if I want to display the sender's IP address.

Comment: Did you compile? What was the result?

Comment: @Anwar I did compile rsyslogd because I was adding support for the MongoDB plugin at the time, however I don't recall if I did anything with this particular issue.  Sorry, it's been a while.